# Menu stopped working

Tags: javascript, html, menu

Could someone please look at the menu on this webpage:

http://www.henryscafebar.co.uk/Home.aspx

For some reason the menu options after 'Choose your venue' have stopped working and for the life of me I cannot see why.

The only thing that has been added to the page is the Mother's Day banner at the top, but I'm not reading any JS errors in Firebug.

Thanks.

Comment: i don't see any onmouseover event for the rest of the menu items

Comment: Try and avoid asking people *directly* to fix your site. It's not going to make you very popular on SO.

Comment: I disagree with the closure - overlapping elements are a problem, I just couldn't see it. Thank you to Purmou who was the first to spot it. SO is a strange place sometimes.

Comment: I closed this as too localized because there was no way for anyone to know the problem without going to the site, and we usually like to include the problematic code in the question itself instead of linking. Just for future users to have reference in case the page linked to goes down. But I also answered since I believe everyone deserves help here as a programmer. :)

Comment: I agree, the problem with the code is not knowing which bit was at fault. I'd looked over the elements but really couldn't see it, as per my question, I thought it was a Javascript error. But I'll note your comments for the future, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mother's Day banner is covering up the rest of the menu, actually.

The `height` CSS property of the banner is causing the problems. Setting it to 100, for example, fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You Mother's Day banner container overruns the menu... fix that.

Answer (score 0):

It has not stopped working. The div mothers-day-banner is over the menu, so you can't hover it